# Passing data from .vue to .js in vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am doing report through chartjs.

In `User.vue`

```
beforeCreate() {
    axios
      .get("/pct-at/api/users")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      startDate: "",
    };
  },
```

**Result res.data :**

```
{"datasets":[{"label":"User active","data":[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"fill":false,"borderColor":"#9ec6cb"}}
```

In userChart.js

```
export default {
    lineChart: {
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            backgroundColor: false,
            hover: {
                mode: 'label',
            },
        },
        data: data // I want to get data from User.vue here : data
    },
}
```

Now I want in user.js to receive data in res.data from User.vue, how should I do that? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this data in .js file? Please clarify your requirements and also add your full code

Comment: @mayank1513 On my question I also specified that I need to pass API data from .vue to .js in order for me to display chartjs? What more information do you need to help me?

Comment: I have added link to vue-chart-js official guide in my answer. Please follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to fetch data via axios call in `userChart.js` itself.

If you want to communicate between components, you can use custom events and props, event bus or [mitt](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#migration-strategy).

Specifically for `chart.js`, please follow the official guide [here](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/).